# device handle in GetTextExtentPoint32()

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, libharu

I want to use `GetTextExtentPoint32` to compute the size of the string in pixels. `GetTextExtentPoint32` has the follwoing syntax:

```
BOOL GetTextExtentPoint32(
  _In_  HDC     hdc,
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpString,
  _In_  int     c,
  _Out_ LPSIZE  lpSize
);
```

where `hdc [in]` is the handle to the device context.

**QUESTIONS:**

I am using the following code to load ***fonts*** in *libharu*

```
    //-----UTF8 Encoding
    HPDF_UseUTFEncodings(pdf);
    const char *fontname = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile(pdf, "FreeSans.ttf", HPDF_TRUE);
    HPDF_Font font = HPDF_GetFont(pdf, fontname, "UTF-8");
```

How to I pass/compute the ***device handle*** to **GetTextExtentPoint32()**?

**UPDATE:**
I am using Win-7 on a monitor of resolution (1920x1080). My aim is to generate a PDF report using ***Libharu*** libraries. I want to compute the length of a string in pixels and for that purpose, I want to use `GetTextExtentPoint32()`

Comment: You can use device handle returned from a GetDC(NULL) call to feed it to the CreateCompatibleDC function. Then you have a DC that you can use in GetTextExtentPoint32. However, you first need to SelectObject the font into that DC. For that purpose you need to get the HFONT handle from the HPDF_Font somehow.

Comment: Result from `GetTextExtentPoint32` will probably be in different measurement than you want. How about `HPDF_Font_GetUnicodeWidth` or `HPDF_Font_TextWidth`? I don't know that library, I am just quoting from [here](http://libharu.sourceforge.net/font_handling.html)

Comment: The extend returned by `GetTextExtentPoint32` is for the font that you have loaded into the device. Are you able to load your font into a device?

Comment: @David: I can load my fonts. My final aim is to write to a PDF file (using libharu) and I want to know the size of a string in pixels. I am already able to write with my current fonts to the PDF.

Comment: You will need a Windows HFONT to work with GDI. Do you have one? Further, what sort of device do you want the pixel count to be relative to. There are more pixels on the printed page than the screen for instance. What is missing from your question is any appreciation of that because you make no mention as to what device you intend to use.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Please check the update. I am not sure if I have provided the necessary information now.

Comment: You are assuming, that any given PDF renderer uses the same font rendering used inside Windows 7. That is in general not the case. What issue are you really trying to solve?

Comment: For the life of me I cannot see how the pixel count on your particular monitor relates to PDF documents. It seems like you have a deep disconnect somewhere. What problem are you actually trying to solve.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: This is a simple example of the problem that I am trying to solve.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024403/calculate-string-length-in-pixels-to-create-strings-of-equal-lengths

Comment: Good. Now, in that question, what is the context in which you want to measure pixels? Surely it's the PDF file that you are working with. In which case how could `GetTextExtentPoint32` help? Unfortunately you have asked a question about your solution rather than your problem. Your question is easy to answer but it won't help you because you have chosen a solution that does not solve your problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: My main aim is to solve the problem as mentioned in the above link. I thought that `GetTextExtentPoint32` could help me to solve that problem. Is there any other way to solve that problem?

Comment: I'm sure you can solve your problem, but not with `GetTextExtentPoint32` unless I am very much mistaken. At this current question, all we can do is answer what you have asked, which won't help you I think. You see our predicament.

Comment: You can also generate PDF's using Qt library it is very easy with QTextDocument class

Comment: @skm you will need to learn how coordinates are measured in PDFs and see if libharu or some other library provides a function to measure the length of a string in those units.

Comment: look at: http://libharu.sourceforge.net/font_handling.html#HPDF_Font_GetXHeight_ if you still want to use libharu, but this function set seams to have a poor functionality for callculating real text size.

Comment: @Mykola [the x-height is not what you think it is](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/Art/glyph_metrics_2x.png). `HPDF_Font_TextWidth()` and `HPDF_Font_MeasureText()` seem to be more along the lines of what the OP is asking for, but they are not particularly well documented.

Comment: @andlabs: I wasn't intended to recommend to use X-Height, but entire documentation page for OP investigation.

Comment: @andlabs: So as you said, it is not well documented library.

Comment: @Mykola ah okay, sorry for the confusion then

Comment: I ahve already tried to use `HPDF_Font_TextWidth()` and `HPDF_Font_MeasureText()` but they don't give me precise results.

Comment: This is now something of a disaster zone. Question about an API function totally unrelated to the comments and the answer and the actual problem.

Comment: @David Heffernan I'm totaly agree with your opinion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is a textbook case study in the XY Problem (GetTextExtent32() is the Y)

Answer (score 1):

So to get the width of a string of text in your PDF with libharu, use `HPDF_Font_TextWidth()`. This returns a `HPDF_TextWidth` structure; use its `width` field. The width will be measured in either **1/1000th of an em** or **1000 ems**, I'm not sure which (using whatever sense of "em" TrueType uses for the em square), which I'm assuming PDF uses natively for measurements. You'd have to check the rest of HPDF's documentation.

I'm not sure if this takes kerning into consideration or not.

Confirmation: the source of HPDF's general font handling, the source of HDPF's TrueType font handling, Apple's TrueType font reference. The exact calculation is

width of one glyph = advance_width(units) * 1000 / units_per_em

Comment: Thanks, I already tried to use it but as I mentioned in my comment before, it wasn't precise (actually too bad).

Comment: @skm how exactly is it inaccurate? You didn't say that yet. Is it longer than the actual size, but only slightly? If so, that would be the kerning thing I was mentioning. Is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Windows GDI works with pixels. Haru PDF works with points (72 points/inch). There is no direct equivalent to `GetTextExtentPoint32()` in Haru PDF.

If you want to duplicate your GDI results in PDF, you will need to:

[1] Call `GetTextExtentPoint32()` to get the text size in GDI pixels.

[2] Divide the width in pixels by the Device Context resolution (pixels/inch), then multiply by 72 to get points. Call `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX)` to get the pixels/inch. Call this result `fTargetWidth`. This is how wide you expect your string to be.

[3] When writing the PDF, call `HPDF_Font_TextWidth()` to get the string's width as seen from Haru. If the PDF width is greater than GDI's "points" width, tighten the spacing a tad, subtracting the excess over the range of characters:

```
// how long is this string?
HPDF_TextWidth htw = HPDF_Font_TextWidth(pdfFont, (HPDF_BYTE *)string, len);
// convert to actual points
fWidth = (htw.width * fontPoints) / 1000.f;
// does it overflow?
if(fWidth > fTargetWidth && htw.numchars > 0)
{   excess = fWidth - fTargetWidth;    // by how much
    charSpace = -excess / htw.numchars;  // note negative
    // tighten up the spacing
    HPDF_Page_SetCharSpace(page, charSpace);
}

HPDF_Page_TextOut (page, x, y, string);
HPDF_Page_SetCharSpace(page, 0.f);      // reset
```

For some reason, `HPDF_Page_SetWordSpace()` doesn't seem to have any effect.

How come the same font, at the same size, has such a difference in width? So much for WYSIWYG  :o)